# Dajaxice function not registering on server

Tags: django, bluehost, dajaxice

So I had no problems getting Dajaxice to work on my development server.  However, now that I'm trying to deploy to a production server (Bluehost), I'm getting the following error in the Firebug console:

```
TypeError: Dajaxice.user is undefined
```

Where `user` is the first part of the name I gave my function when registering it as follows:

```
@dajaxice_register(method='GET', name='user.stuff')
```

Typing in Dajaxice returns things, and autocomplete shows that its methods are available.  So I'm guessing this means that my function is just not registering for some reason.  How can I solve this?